# How do I disable a specific FxCop rule in generated code?

Tags: .net, fxcop

I had a problem where I needed to disable a certain rule (in this case CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays) for generated code. If it was my own code, I would have just added a `SuppressMessage` Attribute to the given function and that's it. Obviously, I can't do that in generated code because it will be lost on the next build.

Automatically generated code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ListViewTable {

    private ListViewTableRow[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Row", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ListViewTableRow[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Items` property generates

```
 <Message TypeName="PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays" Category="Microsoft.Performance" CheckId="CA1819" Status="Active" Created="2013-10-29 14:47:04Z" FixCategory="Breaking">
         <Issue Certainty="50" Level="Warning" Path="D:\Projects\FlightPlanning\src\Core\FpesCustomControls" File="AoiSchema.cs" Line="32">Change 'ListViewTable.Items' to return a collection or make it a method.</Issue>
        </Message>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem, module-level suppressions can be used. In any other source file of the project, the following statement can be used (must be right after the using directives):

```
[module: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays", Justification = "Generated code",
Scope = "member", Target = "FlightPlanning.AoiSchema.ListViewTable.#Items")]
```

The difficulty is finding the right name for the Target, because it must be an exact fully qualified string. Luckily, the FxCop gui offers help to generate the correct message: Just right-click the error, select "Copy-As" and choose "Module level Suppression"

Comment: From the GUI you can also select "Suppress Message" and select "In Suppression File" (instead of "In Source") for the same effect.

Comment: I have that option when I right-click on the message in the CodeAnalysis window. But I do *not* have that "Copy-To", just a "Copy", strange. Are you maybe using the old FxCop plugin instead of the now built-in CodeAnalysis?

Comment: I don't have a built-in tool, it's a separate GUI. Is this CodeAnalyis a separate download or is it only available for VS2012? I'm currently still using VS2010.

Comment: It's in VS2010, but you need Premium or higher.

Comment: Ok, I have professional "only". I'll have to go with the manual way it seems :-(