# How do I suppress CA1725?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

### What I have

I want to implement a synchronous replacement for a BackgroundWorker, to use in my NUnit testing.  From my research I currently have this:

```
    // Interface:
    public interface IBackgroundWorker
    {
        // The properties, events and methods from BackgroundWorker go here
    }
    public delegate IBackgroundWorker BackgroundWorkerFactory();
    // Implementation 1:
    public class MyBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker, IBackgroundWorker
    {
        private MyBackgroundWorker() { }
        public static MyBackgroundWorker Factory()
            { return new MyBackgroundWorker(); }
    }
    // Implementation 2 is a synchronous version
```

However, FxCop whinges with this gem:

> Change parameter name 'param0' of method MyBackgroundWorker.MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(Boolean)Void to 'value' in order to match the identifier as it has been declared in IBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(Boolean)Void.

(It says something similar about `RunWorkerAsync(object)`, as that's the only other method on the interface which takes a parameter)

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182251.aspx) says I shouldn't suppress the message, but [this](http://www.databaseforum.info/30/579612.aspx) says that I should, as it's simply a compiler-generated problem and a version 1.36 of FxCop fixes it.

### What I want

I want to use this thin wrapper rather than needing to proxy each method and property through to an enclosed object (which would be do-able, and would avoid the problem, but is not ideal as a future-proofed design).

I then want to suppress the message from FxCop 1.35, preferably using a `SuppressMessage` attribute in the module itself, as the build process is outside of my control (it's managed centrally).

### What I've tried

I've tried several variants of the SuppressMessage, based on what I've found elsewhere on the web, such as [here](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/Sources/Accord.Imaging/Properties/GlobalSuppressions.cs), but none has the desired effect.

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundWorker.#set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.#set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)")]

[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundWorker.#set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)System.Void")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)System.Void")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.#set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)System.Void")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1725", MessageId = "0#", Scope = "member",
    Target = "MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean)System.Void")]
```

Comment: Where is the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` definition?

Comment: My apologies - I've corrected my example to reflect what I actually have at the moment, rather than some mid-edit hybrid.
The `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property is defined in `BackgroundWorker`, and also in `IBackgroundWorker`, with the same signature (Go to definition in each shows the same thing - `bool WorkerSupportsCancellation { get; set; }`).

Comment: Which version of VS are you using and which ruleset because I can't repro this warning with your current code sample.

Comment: I know it's VS2012, and I know that the output includes FxCopCmd, but I can't find where the ruleset is set. `<RunCodeAnalysis>` is false in the project, and `CODE_ANALYSIS` is set in `<DefineConstants>`.

Does the [FxCopCmd.exe.config](http://rickmartin.me.uk/FxCop.exe.Config) file help answer your question?

Comment: I'm on VS2010 Ultimate so that explains the difference...my FxCopCmd.exe is from march, 19th 2010

Comment: That sounds like FxCop 1.36. Mine is FxCop 1.35, and the .exe is dated 23 June 2006.

Comment: Did you get yours from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544)

Comment: I doubt it. Like I said, the installation is managed centrally, and I won't be able to ask until Monday. Even then I doubt I'd get a definitive answer. I'm not surprised you can't reproduce the problem, though, given that you're running FxCop 1.36 - [this site](http://www.databaseforum.info/30/579612.aspx) says that it was fixed in that version.

Comment: You could try to lift the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` with a new modifier to the `MyBackgroundWorker`. That doesn't generate a  (new) warning for me in the normal toolchain but Resharper does detect the akwardness of that construct.

Comment: @rene Yes, but that's an extremely heavyweight workaround for what is, when you come down to it, a MS problem. I found my answer, though, so have posted that for future reference. Thanks for your efforts, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I disable a specific FxCop rule in generated code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662125/how-do-i-disable-a-specific-fxcop-rule-in-generated-code) has the answer - I can get the fully-qualified name (I was right about that being the bit I couldn't get right) from the GUI tool using Copy As -> Module-level SuppressMessage, and it works.

In my case, I need to specify

```
[module: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming",
                         "CA1725",
                         MessageId = "0#",
                         Scope = "member",
                         Target = "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundWorker.MyNamespace.IBackgroundWorker.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(System.Boolean):System.Void")]
```